# ASP.NET Core 3.1 does not load page without "/" at the end of the URL

Tags: asp.net-core, routes, single-page-application, static-files

I have an ASP.NET Core 3.1 MVC application. In Startup.cs I set PathBase with following configurations

```
        public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
        {
            app.UsePathBase("/foo/bar");
            ...

            string spaPath = "/foo/bar";
            app.Map(spaPath, appBuilder => {
                appBuilder.UseSpa(spa =>
                {
                    spa.Options.DefaultPage = spaPath + "/index.html";
                    spa.Options.DefaultPageStaticFileOptions = new StaticFileOptions
                    {
                        RequestPath = spaPath,
                    };
                    spa.Options.SourcePath = "ClientApp";
                    if (env.IsDevelopment())
                    {
                        spa.UseReactDevelopmentServer(npmScript: "start");
                    }
                });
            });

        }
```

After publishing It perfectly works, but only with "/" at the end of the URL(http://server/foo/bar/). But if I delete last character, application can't find some static files. Instead of requesting http://server/foo/bar/css/2.ce0fb376.chunk.css, application tries to get this files from http://server/foo/css/2.ce0fb376.chunk.css and expectedly does not find it. Is there any way for setting path where application will try to looking for this files?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: UsePathBase() doesn't work if the specified path base doesn't match the path in the request. Your SPA is requesting for foo/css/xxx.css, which does not start with /foo/bar, so the path base middleware is skipped entirely, and ASP.NET Core naturally tries to serve foo/css/xxx.css which doesn't exist. The problem probably lies with your SPA and not ASP.NET Core. For example, for React you may want to look at [this](https://create-react-app.dev/docs/deployment/#building-for-relative-paths).

Comment: Yea, I understand. I tried to redirect it If request was from foo/css/xxx.css to foo/bar/css/xxx.css, but, as I understamd, step of redirection comes after launching SPA and loading all static files. Is there any way to say application that the requst server/foo/bar must hosted on server/foo/bar/ and not in server/foo/ with "bar" attribute, folder or action, which application tries to parse it. Thanx